# VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update How can i fix this problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am facing an error that says "VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc." Can anyone help me to fix this problem in my code? Also, sometimes posts load after 2-3 secs of time how can I load intensely?

MainPage:

```
export default function Home({ navigation }) {
  const [userdata, setUserdata] = useState(null);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar />
      <ButtomNavbar navigation={navigation} page={'home'} />
      <TopNavbar navigation={navigation} page={'home'} />
      <Posts />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Post Comp:

```
import { StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback  } from 'react';
import PostCard from '../Cards/PostCard';


const Posts = () => {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);

    const fetchUserData = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3000/postdata');
            const data = await response.json();
            setUserData(data);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchUserData();
    }, [fetchUserData]);

    return (
        <FlatList
            style={styles.container}
            data={userData}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                <PostCard
                    key={index}
                    username={item.username}
                    profile_image={item.profile_image}
                    postImage={item.postImage}
                />
            )}
        />
    );
}

export default Posts
```

Post Card:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';

const PostCard = ({ username, profile_image, postImage }) => {

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.c1}>
        <Image source={{ uri: profile_image }} style={styles.profilepic} />
        <Text style={styles.username}>{username}</Text>
      </View>
      <Image source={{ uri: postImage }} style={styles.image} />

    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Limit the API response data and call API again before the end of scrolling.

Comment: @SahilArdeshna Can you give out a code example? it would be much helpful

Comment: Sorry, I only answered to guide you and let you know this is possible. Now it's your turn to find that solution and code on your own to learn how it's done. Thanks

Comment: The error seems to imply it's `<PostCard/>` that is slow, your not showing this so it's hard to tell what that might be..

Comment: @SahilArdeshna if you mean this http://10.0.2.2:3000/postdata?limit=20 i did this but that warn don't even go

Comment: @Keith What do you mean? what to show?

Comment: Your code for `<PostCard/>` is not in your question, it's that what the error is complaining about.

Comment: @Keith Please Check again i did

Comment: @Jack you mean you just have, not that you did.. :)

Comment: @Keith What can i do?

Comment: I assume there are lots of records?, if so you will be better using ->  https://reactnative.dev/docs/virtualizedlist   This will then only render what's in view, rather than the full dataset.

Comment: @Keith i am focusing on my app speed what would you recommend me should i use flat list or VirtualizedList for a scalable app

Comment: Yes, use VirtualizedList,  there specifically designed to render thousands of items, a normal list will render everything even if not in view, and this takes time.  Looking at your code it should be minimal changes, the main thing you need is something that uniquely identifies the item.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `keyExtractor` prop to your `FlatList`.
Here is an example:

```js
  return (
        <FlatList
            style={styles.container}
            data={userData}
             keyExtractor={(item) => `${item.id}`}  <-----add this line
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                <PostCard
                    key={index}
                    username={item.username}
                    profile_image={item.profile_image}
                    postImage={item.postImage}
                />
            )}
        />
    );
```

Comment: Here is a decent reference for why you should do this https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-to-use-keyextractor-prop-in-react-natives-flatlist/

Answer (score 0):

`"VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc."`

This warning basically appear when you try to render too much data or objects using FlatList because when you have good amount of data , you have to manage that it will not be render again and again as `renderItem` call again and again with data when user scroll which consume more memory

You can control this behaviour by creating renderItem class component and extend it with `PureComponent` instead of `React.Component`

You can also control this behaviour by `shouldComponentUpdate` method as shown in this example

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-does-shouldcomponentupdate-do-and-why-is-it-important/

If you think it is going to take your time then as simplest solution you can use this lib

https://shopify.github.io/flash-list/